# Amazon Connect Contact Flow CLI/API

Tags: amazon-connect

So I am looking at how I can use the new CLI/API features to a pipeline so that a Contact Flow in Dev can be deployed to Testing and then onto Prod.

But I have found the format of the CLI/API 'content' attribute expects a different JSON format to that of the export/import feature within the UI.

Has anyone tried this and got it working?

Answer (score 1):

So the export/import format of the JSON is different from the UI so you cannot use the AWS CLI/ Connect API to import the file.

So you need to use the describe-contact-flow CLI/API to get the correctly formatted JSON and then use the create/update contact flow CLI/API for it to work. It will not work by using the UI Import facility.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer.  I spent a while wondering why the API wasn't taking the UI exported JSON and found this answer.  I would also add that the JSON as it comes out of the API/CLI can be imported directly, with no modification required.  I was wondering about that and it looks like it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest waiting for the next release, Amazon has inferred this the first of many changes that they are deploying for DevOps around Contact Flows.